# Want to display full name of customer in c++

Tags: c++

```
char custname[50];
```

User name is custname of array with 50 values in it.

```
cin>>custname;
cout<<custname;
```

How It should take firstname middlename lastname of customer in array.

I did a C++ Program in which I want to enter my customers full name and also want to display it. Whenever I enter the name it omit the part after space. I am new to c++ so please any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Operator `>>` of `std::cin` reads a string up to the first separator. If you want to read the whole line as string, use `std::getline()` function instead.

Also, do not store string as `char[]` in this case, use `std::string` instead.